# Perl drop down menus and Unicode

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've been going around on this for some time now and can't quite get it. This is Perl 5 on Ubuntu. I have a drop down list on my web page:

```
$output .= start_form . "Student: " . popup_menu(-name=>'student', -values=>['', @students], -labels=>\%labels, -onChange=>'Javascript:submit()') . end_form;
```

It's just a set of names in the form "Last, First" that are coming from a SQL Server table. The labels are created from the SQL columns like so:

```
$labels{uc($record->{'id'})} = $record->{'lastname'} . ", " . $record->{'firstname'};
```

The issue is that the drop down isn't displaying some Unicode characters correctly. For instance, "Søren" shows up in the drop down as "SÃ¸ren". I have in my header:

```
use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

...and I've also played around with various takes on the "**decode( )**" function, to no avail. To me, the funny thing is that if I pull **$labels** into a test script and print the list to the console, the names appear just fine! So what is it about the drop down that is causing this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

This is the relevant functionality, which I've stripped down to this script that runs in the console and *yields the correct results* for three entries that have Unicode characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use lib '/home/web/library';
use mssql_util;
use Encode;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

$query = "[SQL query here]";

$dbh  = &connect;
$sth  = $dbh->prepare($query);
$result = $sth->execute();

while ($record = $sth->fetchrow_hashref())
{
        if ($record->{'id'})
        {
                $labels{uc($record->{'id'})} = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $record->{'lastname'} . ", " . $record->{'nickname'} . " (" . $record->{'entryid'} . ")");
        }
}

$sth->finish();

print "$labels{'ST123'}\n";
print "$labels{'ST456'}\n";
print "$labels{'ST789'}\n";
```

The difference in what the production script is doing is that instead of printing to the console like above, it's printing to HTTP:

```
$my_output = "<p>$labels{'ST123'}</p><br>
              <p>$labels{'ST456'}</p><br>
              <p>$labels{'ST789'}</p>";

$template =~ s/\$body/$my_output/;

print header(-cookie=>$cookie) . $template;
```

This gives, i.e., strings like "ZoÃ«" and "SÃ¸ren" on the page. BUT, if I remove `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` from the top of the production script, then the strings appear just fine on the page (i.e. I get "Zoë" and "Søren").

I believe that the binmode( ) line is necessary when writing UTF-8 to output, and yet removing it here produces the correct results. What gives?

Comment: You need to check the $record->{'lastname'} and $record->{'firstname'} utf8 flag use Encode:is_utf8(). If they are all utf8 or not, you can concat them.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sprintf "%vX", $value` for a string that doesn't work well, and provide what you expect to see for that string.

Comment: **Never** use `Encode::is_utf8` except in debug statements. Code that relies on its result is guaranteed to be buggy.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami. I get: 53.C3.B8.72.65.6E, for a string that I expect to appear as "Søren" but instead is appearing as "SÃ¸ren". My test script correctly prints "Søren" and "53.F8.72.65.6E" to the console.

Comment: It would seem that I'm reading from the database just fine, and that it is the HTTP response encoding that is causing the problem (as Dave is, I think, suggesting below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem #1: Decoding inputs**

`53.C3.B8.72.65.6E` is the UTF-8 encoding for `Søren`. When you instruct Perl to encode it all over again (by printing it to handle with the `:utf8` layer), you are producing garbage.

You need to decode your inputs (`$record->{id}`, `$record->{lastname}`, `$record->{firstname}`, etc)! This will transform The UTF-8 bytes `53.C3.B8.72.65.6E` ("encoded text") into the Unicode Code Points `53.F8.72.65.6E` ("decoded text").

In this form, you will be able to use `uc`, regex matches, etc. You will also be able to print them out to a handle with an encoding layer (e.g. `:encoding(UTF-8)`, or the improper `:utf8`).

You let on that these inputs come from a database. Most DBD have a flag that causes strings to be decoded. For example, if it's a MySQL database, you should pass `mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1` to `connect`.

---

**Problem #2: Communicating encoding**

If you're going to output UTF-8, don't tell the browser it's ISO-8859-1!

```
$ perl -e'use CGI qw( :standard ); print header()'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Fixed:

```
$ perl -e'use CGI qw( :standard ); print header( -type => "text/html; charset=UTF-8" )'
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. When I removed the `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")` and used `Encode::decode('UTF-8', $record->{'lastname'} . ", " . $record->{'nickname'})` - all was well. Thank you for your help. I'm just starting to learn how encoding and character sets work so I appreciate the patience.

Comment: NO!!! Keep `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")`. You need to encode your outputs!

Comment: Retaining `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")` causes the output to revert to garbage though. I'm confused...

Comment: Then you have an additional problem to fix you mentioned nothing about.

Comment: I edited my post with a more comprehensive code snippet. I can't think of what else to provide, but I do appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Inserting `-type => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"` did it. It was strange because we have that built into the page's template, and yet typing `document.characterSet` in Chrome's console still yielded `windows-1252`. Your fix corrects it, but I still wonder why the browser wasn't picking up our <meta> tag in the HTML template...but that's a question for another thread!

Comment: The actual header must override the "header-equivalent" tag

Answer (score 2):

Hard to give a definitive solution as you don't give us much useful information. But here are some pointers that might help.

- `use utf8` only tells Perl that your source code is encoded as UTF-8. It does nothing useful here.
- Reading [perldoc perlunitut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) would be a good start.
- Do you know how your database tables are encoded?
- Do you know whether your database connection is configured to automatically decode data coming from the database into Perl characters?
- What encoding are you telling the browser that you have encoded your HTTP response in?

Comment: I'm not a Perl developer, or even much of a web developer; this just landed in my lap, so I appreciate the direction. The database tables are encoded as "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS". The database connection utilizes DBI...I'm fairly certain that it is automatically decoding, since the same code is writing the proper characters to the console in my test script. That's what leads me to believe that your third question is the key here. How can I determine my HTTP response encoding?

Comment: To be clear, the HTML header has <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />, which I take to mean that the browser expects UTF-8, which I think is what you meant by your third question.